# PHP equivalent to ASP.NET / SharePoint Webparts?

Tags: php, sharepoint, web-parts

Is there a PHP equivalent to Webparts? I'm looking for an alternative to the user-pluggable, connectable, customisable application building blocks that are part of SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

The modules in phpNuke act a lot like SharePoint webparts.

Comment: I'm new to PHP, so forgive me if I've missed something. Webparts are pluggable and configurable by the end-user while the application is running. From what I've found in searching, modules are added by the developer, not the end user. Also, webparts are connectable so that a value selected in one can be used in another, such as to filter a list. Does phpNuke have this capability?

Comment: or drupal (Please enter at least 15 characters.)